# How to test a logistic regression model in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, kaggle

I'm developing a CTR prediction model for the Kaggle competition ([link](https://www.kaggle.com/c/avazu-ctr-prediction)). I've read in the first 100,000 lines of data from the training set, then further split this into train/test sets at 80/20 by

```
ad_data <- read.csv("train", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, nrows = 100000)
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(ad_data$click, p=0.8, list=FALSE, times=1)
ad_train <- ad_data[trainIndex,]
ad_test <- ad_data[-trainIndex,]
```

then I used the ad_train data to develop a GLM model

```
ad_glm_model <- glm(ad_train$clicks ~ ad_train$C1 + ad_train$site_category + ad_train$device_type, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = ad_train)
```

But whenever I try to use the predict function to check out how well it does on the ad_test set, I get the error:

```
test_model <- predict(ad_glm_model, newdata = ad_test, type = "response")
Warning message:
'newdata' had 20000 rows but variables found have 80000 rows
```

What gives? How do I test my GLM model on new data?

EDIT: It works perfectly. Just need to do this call instead:

```
ad_glm_model <- glm(clicks ~ C1 + site_category + device_type, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = ad_train)
```

Comment: dont use `ad_train$` in the glm call, just use `data=` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are including the name of the data frame for each variable in the model formula. Instead, your formula should be:

```
glm(clicks ~ C1 + site_category + device_type, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = ad_train)
```

As described in [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464893/getting-warning-newdata-had-1-row-but-variables-found-have-32-rows-on-pred) in the duplicate notification:

> This is a problem of using different names between your data and your
>   newdata and not a problem between using vectors or dataframes.
>
> When you fit a model with the lm function and then use predict to make
>   predictions, predict tries to find the same names on your newdata. In
>   your first case name x conflicts with mtcars$wt and hence you get the
>   warning.