# R codes, newdata' had 73 rows but variables found have 371380 rows

Tags: r, glm, glm-math, error-code

I am trying to run this code but I have an error
could you help

```
Ag<-read.table("/Users/Desktop//AGE.csv", header=T)
PoGLM<-glm(tdt$NC.x~AGEF, family=poisson(link="log"))
prf<-predict(PoGLM,newdata=Ag, type="response")
Warning message:
'newdata' had 73 rows but variables found have 371380 rows
```

Comment: Please read about [minimal, complete, verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is difficult to do much without seeing something reproducible.

Comment: This is occurring because the regression formula restates the data frame name (`tdt$NC.x~AGEF` rather than `NC.x~AGEF`). Code should be `glm(NC.x ~ AGEF, family=poisson(link="log"), data=tdt)`. See [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27465510/496488) for an explanation.