# predic.lm gives wrong number of predicted values when I fit and predict a model using a matrix variable

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, prediction, lm

In the past I've used the `lm` function with `matrix`-type data and `data.frame`-type. But I guess this is the first time that I tried to use `predict` using a model fitted without a `data.frame`. And I'm can't figure out how to make it work.

I read some other questions (such as [Getting Warning: " 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 32 rows" on predict.lm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464893/getting-warning-newdata-had-1-row-but-variables-found-have-32-rows-on-pred)) and I'm pretty sure that my problem is related with the coefficient names I'm getting after fitting the model. For some reason the coefficients names are a paste of the matrix name with the column name... and I haven't been able to find how to fix that...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(MASS)

set.seed(1)
label <- sample(c(T,F), nrow(Boston), replace = T, prob = c(.6,.4))

x.train <- Boston %>% dplyr::filter(., label) %>%
  dplyr::select(-medv) %>% as.matrix()
y.train <- Boston %>% dplyr::filter(., label) %>%
  dplyr::select(medv) %>% as.matrix()
x.test <- Boston %>% dplyr::filter(., !label) %>%
  dplyr::select(-medv) %>% as.matrix()
y.test <- Boston %>% dplyr::filter(., !label) %>%
  dplyr::select(medv) %>% as.matrix()

fit_lm <- lm(y.train ~ x.train)
fit_lm2 <- lm(medv ~ ., data = Boston, subset = label)
predict(object = fit_lm, newdata = x.test %>% as.data.frame()) %>% length() 
predict(object = fit_lm2, newdata = x.test %>% as.data.frame()) %>% length()
# they get different numbers of predicted data
# the first one gets a number a results consistent with x.train
```

Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't fix your `tidyverse` code because I don't work with this package. But I am able to explain why `predict` fails in the first case.

Let me just use the built-in dataset `trees` for a demonstration:

```
head(trees, 2)
#  Girth Height Volume
#1   8.3     70   10.3
#2   8.6     65   10.3
```

The normal way to use `lm` is

```
fit <- lm(Girth ~ ., trees)
```

The variable names (on the RHS of `~`) are

```
attr(terms(fit), "term.labels")
#[1] "Height" "Volume"
```

You need to provide these variables in the `newdata` when using `predict`.

```
predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(Height = 1, Volume = 2))
#       1 
#11.16125
```

Now if you fit a model using a matrix:

```
X <- as.matrix(trees[2:3])
y <- trees[[1]]
fit2 <- lm(y ~ X)
attr(terms(fit2), "term.labels")
#[1] "X"
```

The variable you need to provide in `newdata` for `predict` is now `X`, not `Height` or `Girth`. Note that since `X` is a matrix variable, you need to protect it with `I()` when feeding it to a data frame.

```
newdat <- data.frame(X = I(cbind(1, 2)))
str(newdat)
#'data.frame':  1 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ X: AsIs [1, 1:2] 1 2

predict(fit2, newdat)
#       1 
#11.16125
```

It does not matter that `cbind(1, 2)` has no column names. What is important is that this matrix is named `X` in `newdat`.