# lm in R, despite name matching: "Warning message: 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have x rows"

Tags: r

```
set.seed(1)
y <- rnorm(6)
x <- matrix(rnorm(12),6,2)
my.lm <- lm(y~x)
predict(my.lm, newdata=data.frame(x1=4,x2=0))
```

This results in the following warning and incorrect output: "Warning message:
'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 6 rows".

I understand, as [others have pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464893/getting-warning-newdata-had-1-row-but-variables-found-have-32-rows-on-pred) that this error is due to the variable name in the lm not matching the variable name in predict. But in this case, they match. The variable names are "x1" and "x2" when you print the `my.lm` object.

My question is, how do I predict using `lm` when the x object is a matrix. I don't want to have to convert the whole thing to data frames. Is it possible?

Comment: What is so onerous about converting this matrix to a frame?

Comment: And they don't match, because the model formula is defined with a single dependent variable `x`, regardless of what the representation of the model is when printed on the console.

Comment: Are you telling me it's impossible to use predict if the X object used in the lm is a matrix?

Answer (score 2):

To get `predict()` to work with an `lm` model fitted using a matrix, you need to pass a data frame containing a matrix of values to use in the prediction.  Here's an example showing a model using a data frame and a a model using a matrix:

```r
set.seed(1)
y <- rnorm(6)
x <- matrix(rnorm(12),6,2)
df <- cbind(y, as.data.frame(x))

my_lm_df <- lm(y ~ ., df)
my_lm_matrix <- lm(y~x)

predict_df <- data.frame(V1 = 4:6, V2 = 0:2)
predict_matrix <- data.frame(x = I(matrix(c(4:6, 0:2), ncol = 2)))

predict(my_lm_df, newdata = predict_df)
#>         1         2         3 
#> -2.052187 -2.916319 -3.780451
predict(my_lm_matrix, newdata = predict_matrix)
#>         1         2         3 
#> -2.052187 -2.916319 -3.780451
```

Answer (score 2):

For your one row case, it could be as simple as:

```
predict(my.lm, newdata=list(x=cbind(4,0))) # list with single one row matrix
#        1 
#-2.052187 

predict(my.lm, newdata=data.frame(x=matrix(c(4,0),1) ))
#        1 
#-2.052187 
# also succeeds
```

It needs to be an object that can be coerced to a data.frame. Matrices inside dataframes are sometimes handled as single named objects.

Comment: The `list` thing is interesting, but I can't seem to get `predict(my.lm, newdata=data.frame(x=matrix(c(4, 0), 1))` to work.

Comment: It succeeds for me.

Comment: Strange, I'm getting a six-length vector with that warning.

Answer (score 1):

In `stats::lm()`, your call `lm(y ~ x)`, where `x` is a matrix, creates a `model.frame` with just one column for the right-hand side.

```
> ## stats::lm
> formula <- y ~ x
> ret.x <- x
> ret.y <- y
> cl <- mf <- my.lm$call
> m <- match(c("formula", "data", "subset", "weights", "na.action", 
+              "offset"), names(mf), 0L)
> mf <- mf[c(1L, m)]
> mf[[1L]] <- quote(stats::model.frame)
> (mf <- eval(mf, parent.frame()))
           y         x.1         x.2
1 -0.6264538  0.48742905 -0.62124058
2  0.1836433  0.73832471 -2.21469989
3 -0.8356286  0.57578135  1.12493092
4  1.5952808 -0.30538839 -0.04493361
5  0.3295078  1.51178117 -0.01619026
6 -0.8204684  0.38984324  0.94383621
```

Although it looks like two x-columns, it is actually only one, which consists of a matrix.

```
> str(data.frame(mf))
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ y: num  -0.626 0.184 -0.836 1.595 0.33 ...
 $ x: num [1:6, 1:2] 0.487 0.738 0.576 -0.305 1.512 ...
> names(mf)
[1] "y" "x"
```

Therefore, we must also specify a `"data.frame"` containing a matrix column so that we can use `predict()` correctly. To get such an object, we may use `base:::as.data.frame.AsIs()`, which preserves the matrix as a column, while `as.data.frame.matrix(matrix(.))` would coerce it to a data frame with the same number of columns as the matrix, which is what we want to avoid.

```
> ## wrong way
> predict(my.lm, newdata=data.frame(x1=4, x2=0))
         1          2          3          4          5          6 
 0.1549458  0.4664358 -0.3962680  0.4478728 -0.6101250 -0.2369803 
Warning message:
'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 6 rows 
>
> ## right way
> predict(my.lm, newdata=base:::as.data.frame.AsIs(cbind(4, 0)))  ## *
        1 
-2.052187
```

<sub><sup>*</sup>`newdata=data.frame(x=I(cbind(4, 0)))`, `newdata=list(x=cbind(4, 0))` give similar results; see the other answers!</sub>

I'm not sure why the option to use matrices is not implemented in `stats:::model.frame.default()` which is internally used in `stats:::predict.lm()`:

```
> ## stats:::predict.lm
> object <- my.lm
> tt <- terms(object)
> Terms <- delete.response(tt)
```

```
> ## providing WRONG number of columns
> (newdata <- data.frame(x1=4, x2=0))
  x1 x2
1  4  0
> str(newdata)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x1: num 4
 $ x2: num 0
> model.frame(formula=Terms, data=newdata, na.action = na.pass, 
+             xlev = object$xlevels)
          x.1         x.2
1  0.48742905 -0.62124058
2  0.73832471 -2.21469989
3  0.57578135  1.12493092
4 -0.30538839 -0.04493361
5  1.51178117 -0.01619026
6  0.38984324  0.94383621
Warning message:
'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 6 rows
```

```
> ## providing CORRECT number of columns
> (newdata <- base:::as.data.frame.AsIs(cbind(4, 0)))
  x.1 x.2
1   4   0
> str(newdata)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ x: num [1, 1:2] 4 0
> model.frame(Terms, data=newdata, na.action = na.pass, 
+             xlev = object$xlevels)
  x.1 x.2
1   4   0
```

To protect us from useless results, a `warning` has been implemented in `stats:::model.frame.default`. To understand where exactly it is triggered, we can take a look at line 57.

```
> (line <- grep('eval\\(predvars', deparse(stats:::model.frame.default)))
[1] 57
> deparse(stats:::model.frame.default)[line]
[1] "    variables <- eval(predvars, data, env)"
> (wrong <- eval(quote(list(x)), envir=data.frame(x1=4, x2=0), enclos=.GlobalEnv))
[[1]]
           [,1]        [,2]
[1,]  0.4874291 -0.62124058
[2,]  0.7383247 -2.21469989
[3,]  0.5757814  1.12493092
[4,] -0.3053884 -0.04493361
[5,]  1.5117812 -0.01619026
[6,]  0.3898432  0.94383621

> (right <- eval(quote(list(x)), envir=base:::as.data.frame.AsIs(cbind(4, 0)), enclos=.GlobalEnv))
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    0
```

In the **right** case *x* is found in the provided `envir=`onment, in the **wrong** case it is not, so the search goes directly to `enclos=` (here `.GlobalEnv` is), as documented in [`?eval`](https://search.r-project.org/R/refmans/base/html/eval.html).

The warning then works something like this:

```
> WARN <- \() warning(
+   sprintf("'newdata' had %d row but variables found had %d row", 
+           nr, nr2), 
+   call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
> if ((nr2 <- nrow(wrong[[1]])) != (nr <- nrow(newdata))) WARN()  ## wrong data
Warning message:
'newdata' had 1 row but variables found had 6 row 
> if ((nr2 <- nrow(right[[1]])) != (nr <- nrow(newdata))) WARN()  ## right data
```

Comment: `predict(my.lm, newdata=data.frame(x=matrix(c(4,0),1) ))` does succeed. The `as.data.frame.list` function has some additional parameters.

Comment: @IRTFM I think this is more about `?I` than `drop=FALSE`. I wondered why *lotus*'s answer would work and digged into it since he was not explaining it.

Comment: Agree. I delete my brilliant idea when Iproduced an error by actually running it.